# Code to Delete the File in Folder

Tags: excel, vba

Below is my code...

```
dim ws as worksheet, rng As Range, filetodelete As String, cmb As ComboBox

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set rng = ws.Range("B11") '(Storage Location of File: E:\ABC)
Set cmb = Me.ComboBox1
filetodelete = rng & "\" & cmb.Text & ".pdf"

Kill filetodelete
```

The code is associated with the Userform commmand button. The command button will delete the file in the storage location checking the filename with the combobox. While running code, its showing runtime error-file not found.

Kindly advise.

Thanks
Salman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just

```
cmb
```

or

```
cmb.Value
```

Comment: Use the immediate window to make sure that filetodelete is actually what you think it is

Comment: That's because you have to tell it to show something.  Either while you are stepping through your code, type `?filetodelete` and hit enter...after you've assigned it a value in the code.  or put `Debug.Print filetodelete` in your code.  Either you aren't getting what you think you are for the path and name, or the file isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
cmb.Caption
```

Not

```
cmb.Text
```

That should fix it.

Comment: Error: Object Doesn't support this property or method.